# c# Loop through Excel file?

Tags: c#

A C# code that loops through a excel file and lists the Excel table/tab on to a message boxs.

Comment: Well that seems like a nice description but what is your question or let me guess: you expect someone doing your job? Something that you've tried/searched that didn't work you would like to ask about?

Comment: Description
I am running a SSIS 2008 task that imports data from an excel spread sheet that has to be manually consolidated from 17 different tables/tabs of the same spread sheet.
What i would like to achieve is a C# code that loops through a spread sheet and list this tabs/tables for script task
I would then save this names as variables,this variable would be used on a foreach loop to loop through each tab/table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to work with Linq To Excel when I can. There is actually a function that gets just the sheet names:

Query Worksheet Names
The GetWorksheetNames() method can be used to retrieve the list of worksheet names in a spreadsheet.

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory("excelFileName");
var worksheetNames = excel.GetWorksheetNames();
```

http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/wiki/UsingLinqToExcel

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code project article that will show you how to retrieve all sheet names from an Excel workbook (I assume this is what you mean with tab).

[C# - Retrieve Excel Workbook Sheet Names.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/getsheetnames.aspx)

Edit: Not sure if the above would get you range (table) names as well, but otherwise you could probably do that if you're using Excel Interop by looping through `workBook.Names` and then checking the `RefersToRange` property of each name (which would return an error if it's not a range).